# Alerts appear and vanish quickly before they can be accepted in newer version of ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, alert, serenity-bdd

In my current automation framework that uses Serenity we recently updated our version of ChromeDriver from version 2.36.54047 to 89.0.4389.23

In the previous version when an alert showed up it was accepted and the automation ran without issue. When I switch back to the new version 89 of chromedriver, the alert shows up and then disappears within a fraction of a second. The test then fails because the alert was not seen by selenium.

Does anyone by any chance know why this would be happening?

In serenity the code looks like:

as(actor).getAlert().accept();

Comment: Can you check that might be SSL certificate issue when the alert is getting displayed